Article usage for plural nouns


How did you spend your internship at Apple?


I talked with co-workers, attended meetings and sent emails
I talked with THE co-workers, attended THE meetings and sent emails


Is it true that both #1 and #2 are correct and idiomatic in terms of articles?
So, In this context, I can use both "zero" and "the" for co-workers and meetings, but I can only use "zero" for emails,
is my understanding correct?

Does this answer your question? Articles: When do I use "a", "the", or "__"?

Only #1 is correct. #2 is incorrect.
There are specific rules about when and how to use articles. But generally speaking, when you refer to a noun in general, you don't use an article:

I talked with co-workers, attended meetings and sent emails.

When you refer to a specific noun, use the. For example:

I talked with the my co-workers on the third floor.
I attended the required meetings.
I sent the emails they instructed me to send.

You might use a or an when you refer to a non-specific noun. Once you've mentioned it, it's no longer non-specific, so you use the. For example:

I talked with a co-worker yesterday. The co-worker told me not to worry.
I attended a meeting last week. The meeting was fun and entertaining.
I sent an email to Brian yesterday. The email was very long, so I hope he read it.

More Info Here

While this is good advice, it simplifies a bit. "The best thing about interning at Apple was the people; the worst thing was the meetings" —this is fine, and awfully close to what the OP proposed. The difference is contextual usage; "the people at Apple are great" is specific enough to use a definite article, since the statement itself is very general. But "I talked to [the] people" is a much more specific scenario, which comes closer to the individual people.
